# Grouping of Sub-Tables while Maintaining Ranges of Time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by, grouping

I'm working with a table that maintains a history of records for each key, alongside a `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` field that signifies when the record changes go in and out of action, respectively:

| KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | FIELD_ONE | FIELD_TWO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-02 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2000-01-03 | 2000-01-04 | 10 | 21 |
| 1 | 2000-01-05 | 2000-01-06 | 11 | 21 |
| 1 | 2000-01-07 | 2000-01-08 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2000-01-09 | 2000-01-10 | 10 | 21 |

`FIELD_TWO` is not relevant for my purposes, and so I'd like to remove it in my extract. I end up with a table like this, in doing so:

| KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | FIELD_ONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-02 | 10 |
| 1 | 2000-01-03 | 2000-01-04 | 10 |
| 1 | 2000-01-05 | 2000-01-06 | 11 |
| 1 | 2000-01-07 | 2000-01-08 | 10 |
| 1 | 2000-01-09 | 2000-01-10 | 10 |

But now, I have records that are pretty much duplicates of one another - the `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` fields are signifying a change that cannot be seen in my sub-table. And so I'd like to "condense" the table to the following result:

| KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | FIELD_ONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-04 | 10 |
| 1 | 2000-01-05 | 2000-01-06 | 11 |
| 1 | 2000-01-07 | 2000-01-10 | 10 |

How can this be achieved?

I, naively, tried to use a `GROUP BY` over `KEY` and `FIELD_ONE` with a `MIN()` and `MAX()` function applied to the `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` fields, but this does not work for the above example, where `FIELD_ONE` changes to and from one value (10, in this example). You, of course, end up with the following:

| KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | FIELD_ONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-10 | 10 |
| 1 | 2000-01-05 | 2000-01-06 | 11 |

I'm working with PL/SQL, but can make the necessary translations from other SQL flavours as long as PL/SQL has the same tools.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Gaps & Island problem. You can use the traditional solution:

```
select key,
  min(start_date) as start_date,
  max(end_date) as end_date, 
  field_one 
from (
  select
    x.*, 
    sum(case when prev_one = field_one and prev_end + 1 = start_date
        then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by key order by start_date) as g
  from (
    select t.*,
      lag(field_one) over(partition by key order by start_date) as prev_one,
      lag(end_date) over(partition by key order by start_date) as prev_end
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by key, g, field_one
```

Result:

```
 KEY  START_DATE  END_DATE   FIELD_ONE 
 ---- ----------- ---------- --------- 
 1    01-JAN-00   04-JAN-00  10        
 1    05-JAN-00   06-JAN-00  11        
 1    07-JAN-00   10-JAN-00  10
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4_YTLOB).